# Why isn't RewriteCond %{HTTPS} returning the correct value?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal, https, no-www

I am working on a Drupal site for which the client has requested that we remove the 'www.' from the URL. This is super easy and I've done it before; I simply comment out the suggested lines in the Drupal-generated .htaccess file like so:

```
# To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Those of you familiar with Drupal's .htaccess will know that the environment variable `protossl` is set towards the top of the file like so:

```
# Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
# if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
# you don't bounce between http and https.
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
```

This is working perfectly on my local environment, but when I deployed the change to the production site it breaks. `www.mysite.com` redirects to `mysite.com` as expected, but `https://www.mysite.com` **also** redirects to `mysite.com` instead of `https://mysite.com`. It seems that the `%{HTTPS}` variable is returning 'off' even when it should be 'on'.

I can go directly to `https://mysite.com` and it works perfectly. The site's Apache access logs show 'https://' where I expect it to be, as do all of my HTTP requests. The site is running on a RackSpace server using a load balancer (only one node in the balancer). The SSL certificate is on the RackSpace load balancer. I have tried the following steps and none have had any results:

- Replace RewriteCond with `RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]`
- Replace RewriteCond with `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$`
- Multiple variations and combinations of the above RewriteCond's
- Added `$conf['https'] = TRUE;` to settings.php

This is driving my coworkers and I crazy. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you are behind a proxy then try: `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` variable.

Answer (score 5):

[anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) has saved the day! The solution was to use the `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` variable just as he suggested. I updated the protocol detection bit of my .htaccess to look like this:

```
# Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
# if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
# you don't bounce between http and https.
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
# The default proto detection provided by Drupal does not work on our
# production server because it sits behind a load-balancing server.
# This additional RewriteCond makes sure we can detect the forwarded proto
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
```

I'm gonna call this a crunchwrap supreme, 'cause it is *good to go*!

Comment: Thank you so much, this totally saved my day :)